# How do you change the colour of the back button icon in Ionic 4?

Tags: sass, ionic4

I am trying to make the back button icon white in the toolbar of my Ionic 4 app. I have added:

```
ion-back-button {
  --color: white;
}
```

in my `global.scss`, but the icon persists in being grey. I *have* managed to make my toolbar title white.

This is my template:

```
<ion-toolbar>
    <ion-buttons slot="start">
        <ion-back-button></ion-back-button>
    </ion-buttons>
    <ion-title>Title</ion-title>
</ion-toolbar>
```

I'd like to be able to simply define a global style to change the colour of all back buttons globally without having to add additional markup to every page with a back button.

Answer (score 3):

Try it in the global.scss with important

```
ion-back-button{
  --color: white !important;
}
```

Placing it within :root works as well per the docs:

https://ionicframework.com/docs/theming/css-variables#setting-values

```
:root {
  ion-back-button {
    --color: red;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the following styles in the global.scss

```
ion-icon.sc-ion-back-button-md , ion-icon.sc-ion-back-button-ios
{
  color: #fff !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem just now, the `--color` variable just doesn't seem to work, however setting `color` instead with the `!important` flag did.

Here is what I did, note the `focused` and `hover` variables do seem to work if you need to change these.

```
  ion-back-button {
    color: #fff !important;
    --color-focused: #fff;
    --color-hover: #fff;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem.   No matter what I tried, I could not change the color of the ion-back-button from gray.   So, I used the Chrome developer tools to inspect the element and learned that a theme for a third-party module that I had loaded was applying that gray color to all **span** tags.  Fortunately, I no longer needed that module, so the answer for me was to simply remove the reference to the theme.

The module that was causing this problem was AWS Amplify.

I am posting this "answer" here to help you or anyone else take a "next step" in resolving this "maddening" problem: use Chrome developer tools to inspect the back button element in the DOM to identify the CSS rule that is being applied.

Answer (score 0):

Check your `variables.css` file there is should be `@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark)` section that relates to dark theme colors. Also you need set color light to ion-back-button.